# SharePoint & Access -> Hyperlink problems

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, hyperlink

I've got a SharePoint Access application (based on one of the templates), should just be a simple Todo-Utility for the group.

I added a field "Link" to the table "Problems", people should insert the JIRA-ID, which should be automatically converted to a link pointing to "http://jira.somedomain.com/bla/blubb/[HERE_THE_ID]".

Every solution is fine with me: "AfterUpdate-Event writing the converted link into the table" is just as fine as "only the short code is saved in the table and the onclick-macro does the job", I don't care.

However, it looks like there is no FollowHyperlink macro available + even if the column is set to "hyperlink" it is only clickable on the client and not when deployed to the sharepoint site.

Any solutions?

Comment: Access is a rapid application development framework, and uses programming methodologies in order to produce business applications. Deployment is a valid programming topic and just because this particular deployment strategy involves SharePoint, doesn't mean this question is off-topic. I move to re-open this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seems to be a problem of non-IE browsers, works fine in IE...